# How to understand branching and commiting with GitHub

Tags: git

Where am I going wrong here? This keeps happening to me.

I `git checkout` onto a branch, change code, and commit it (sometimes pushing it upstream).

I then `git checkout` onto a different branch, change code, and when I go to push it, it pushes the changed code from the other branch.

How can I have two different working branches?

I have had this happen numerous different ways.

Comment: Quick clarification: you do branching and committing with Git. GitHub is just a platform for hosting Git, and it is Git that allows you to do these operations.

Answer (score 1):

In Git, every commit has a parent. Git is all about the *parent chain* — the line of ancestors that runs all the way back from every commit in the repo to the very first commit ever made in this repo.

A branch is just a name for a single commit; pushing a branch  pushes that commit plus its *entire* parent chain. Whatever ancestors are not on the server before pushing, will be on the server after pushing.

So before starting the second branch you would need to check out a commit *earlier* than the one(s) from the first branch that you *don't* want pushed along with the second branch. Otherwise, pushing the second branch pushes the first branch too, exactly as you describe, — because the way you're doing things, the first branch is an ancestor of the second branch.

For example:

```
git switch main
git switch -c branch1
# edit
git add .
git commit -mcoolness

# prepare to start a new independent branch
git switch main
# if you leave out that line, you get the mess you're getting

git switch -c branch2
# edit
git add .
git commit -mexcellence
```

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: I think I understand. So I have been branching off another branch. And if I just checkout back to main, then branch, it should clear out this problem?

Comment: It's not a "problem", it's just not what you intended. If you intend independent branches, that's how to do it. Look, who's in charge here? You are. Your repo is a diagram, a topology of parent chains, like a tree. It is up to you to draw the diagram you want.  If you want two separate branches you obviously need to start both of them at the trunk.